# Empty files in zip when adding swf files

Tags: php

im trying to download swf files from the urls, from number 1752 to number 1760.
I made a code and everything seem ok but the files are broken! their size are 0 and they are empty! (the swf files)
I dont know what is wrong with my code.
here's my code:

```
<?php 

$num = 1753;
$files = array('');
while($num !== 1760){
array_push($files, '');
$num++;
}
print_r($files);
    $zip = new ZipArchive();

$tmp_file = tempnam('.','');
$zip->open($tmp_file, ZipArchive::CREATE);

foreach($files as $file){

    $download_file = file_get_contents($file);

    $zip->addFromString(basename($file),$download_file);

}

$zip->close();

header('Content-disposition: attachment; filename=Resumes.zip');
header('Content-type: application/zip');
readfile($tmp_file);
?>
```

help?

Answer (score 2):

The server does not have a file called `$num.swf`, you're getting a 404 error.

You need to use *double quotes* if you want PHP to interpolate the variable into its value.

```
while($num !== 1760){
    $files[] = "mogobe.walla.co.il/Swf/AssetsClean/Items/IconS/$num.swf";
    $num++;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the protocol prefix as well as the variables interpolation (as Rocket Hazmat answered).

```
while($num !== 1760){
  $files[] = "http://mogobe.walla.co.il/Swf/AssetsClean/Items/IconS/$num.swf";
  $num++;
}
```

Comment: I fixed it but its still showing me empty swf files